# .net program tracing line by line at run time

Tags: .net, profiling, clr, profiler, dottrace

I am working on a project requirement to trace the running program line by line. These programs/ web applications/windows services were developed long time back, pdb files are available.
I was looking at CLRprofilercallback but it is in C++.
Are there any tools which can emit this information.

Comment: You could use the [Managed Debugger api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/debugging/icordebug-interface) to step through the code, but stopping and resuming the application like that will have a significant impact on performance if you need to do it frequently.

Answer (score 0):

For example, JetBrains dotTrace profiler supports Line-by-line profiling mode: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profiling_Guidelines__Choosing_the_Right_Profiling_Mode.html